# Injecting dependencies into background service in Dagger2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have `Shared Preferences` as a dagger singleton component. I need to inject it into background services like `FirebaseInstanceService`. Here's my attempt:

```
public class InstanceIDListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Inject
    Preferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        ((MyApp) getApplication()).getSingletonComponent().inject(this);
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        preferences.setFcmToken(refreshedToken);

    }
}
```

It is used in this way:

```
   <service android:name="com.fcm.InstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
   </service>
```

Should I use `((MyApp) getApplication()).getSingletonComponent().inject(this);` in the `onTokenRefresh` listener? Is this the correct listener to inject dependencies?

Comment: You should inject it once you need it. If you need it there - inject it there. If you need it earlier, or later - inject earlier or later. There is no `correct listener to inject dependencies` at all.

Comment: 'correct listener' I think you mean 'correct callback'? In most cases for a Service you can safely inject in `onCreate()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I've just been hitting my head on this over the last few hours, and found the solution.

With the new Dagger2 version, you can now have your application implement the **HasServiceInjector** interface, which lets you inject stuff into services.

A simple example:

1) Create your services module:

```
@Module
abstract class ServicesModule {

  @ContributesAndroidInjector
  abstract SomeService ProvideSomeService();
}
```

2) Add it to your App component:

```
@Component(modules = {
  AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class,
  AppModule.class,
  ActivitiesModule.class,
  ServicesModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent {

  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder application(App application);

    AppComponent build();
  }

  void inject(App app);
}
```

3) Have your application implement the said interface:

```
public class App extends Application implements HasActivityInjector, HasServiceInjector {

  @Inject
  DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector;
  @Inject
  DispatchingAndroidInjector<Service> serviceInjector;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AppInjector.init(this);
  }

  @Override
  public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
    return activityInjector;
  }

  @Override
  public AndroidInjector<Service> serviceInjector() {
    return serviceInjector;
  }
}
```

4) Finally, inject your service:

```
public class SomeService extends Service {

  @Inject
  SomeDependency dependency;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    AndroidInjection.inject(this);
    super.onCreate();
  }

  // Do things with your dependencies

}
```

I'm using a Service in the example, but my actual use case was with FirebaseInstanceIdService as well. And this worked.

Comment: Its so accurate as i needed